# Finding an invariant form of the tensor product representation of finite group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-products

Given a representation $V$ with a finite group $G$, we have a natural tensor product representation $V^{\otimes n}$ of $G$. In general, $V^{\otimes n}$ is reducible and therefore it can be decomposed into direct sum of irreducible representations. It may have the trivial subrepresentation.

Question: I am particularly interested in the trivial subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes n}$. In other words, I want to know the invariants of $V^{\otimes n}$ under the action of $G$. Is there a systematic way of finding such invariants?

Also, if $G$ is a well-known crystal group, is there any tabulated result about this question?

Comment: Is this over $\mathbb{C}$ or positive characteristic? It matters a lot!

Comment: @DavidCraven It is over $\mathbb C$ indeed! This question motivates from physics, and sorry for not clearly stating the question.

Comment: Then can you not just take the inner product of the character of $V^{\otimes n}$, so $\chi^n$, with the trivial character, so in essence just sum the powers of the character values?

Comment: @DavidCraven By that argument, I can know the multiplicity of the trivial subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes n}$. But, how can I find 'invariants'?

Comment: Ah, so you want them as actual elements of $V^{\otimes n}$, not just the dimensions of the parts. Hmm, let me think.

Comment: Tabulations, for example on p81 of Dave Bensons *Polynomial invariants of finite groups* generally list the degrees of the generators of the ring of invariants, if $G$ is a reflection group. Since $G$ is a polynomial ring in those generators, this might be all you are going to get in general. Of course, armed with the degrees it might be much easier to find explicit representatives, particularly if your group is small.